# How not to render ball orientation in pymunk.Space.debug_draw()?

Tags: python, pygame, pymunk

I am using Pymunk to generate videos of balls bouncing in a frame. To render the frames, I run:

```
import pygame
from pymunk.pygame_util import DrawOptions

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
draw_options = DrawOptions(screen)

# define `space` with six balls
# ...

space.debug_draw(draw_options)
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

As we can see, it draws a black line going from the center to the edge of the ball; I suppose it is to indicate the rotation of each ball.

I would like NOT to have this line drawn: i.e. explicitly pass a flag to prevent pygame from drawing it, or specify the color of this line to be the same as the rest of the ball.

Would anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

The `debug_draw` method should really be used mainly for debugging. I usually create sprite subclasses for my physics objects and give them a Pymunk body and a shape as attributes. Then I can update the `self.rect` in the `update` method by setting the coordinates to the coords of the body and also use it to rotate the image.

```
import math
import random

import pygame as pg
import pymunk as pm
from pymunk import Vec2d


def flipy(p):
    """Convert chipmunk physics to pygame coordinates."""
    return Vec2d(p[0], -p[1]+800)


class Entity(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, space, radius, mass=1):
        super().__init__()
        # The surface is a bit bigger, so that the circle fits better.
        self.orig_image = pg.Surface((radius*2+2, radius*2+2), pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image = self.orig_image
        # Draw a circle onto the image.
        pg.draw.circle(
            self.image,
            pg.Color(random.randrange(256),
                     random.randrange(256),
                     random.randrange(256)),
            (radius+1, radius+1),  # +1 looks a bit better.
            radius)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

        # Create a Pymunk body and a shape and add them to the space.
        moment = pm.moment_for_circle(mass, radius, radius)
        self.body = pm.Body(mass, moment)
        self.shape = pm.Circle(self.body, radius)
        self.shape.friction = .1
        self.shape.elasticity = .99
        self.body.position = pos
        self.space = space
        self.space.add(self.body, self.shape)

    def update(self):
        # Update the rect because it's used to blit the image.
        self.rect.center = flipy(self.body.position)
        # Use the body's angle to rotate the image.
        self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.orig_image, math.degrees(self.body.angle), 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > 1280 or self.rect.y > 790:
            self.space.remove(self.body, self.shape)
            self.kill()


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((1280, 800))
        self.done = False
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

        # Pymunk stuff
        self.space = pm.Space()
        self.space.gravity = Vec2d(0.0, -900.0)
        self.space.damping = .9
        self.static_lines = [
            pm.Segment(self.space.static_body, flipy((60.0, 780.0)), flipy((650.0, 780.0)), .0),
            pm.Segment(self.space.static_body, flipy((650.0, 780.0)), flipy((1218.0, 660.0)), .0)
            ]
        for lin in self.static_lines:
            lin.friction = 0.2
            lin.elasticity = 0.99
        self.space.add(self.static_lines)

        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(60) / 1000
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic()
            self.draw()
            self.current_fps = self.clock.get_fps()

        pg.quit()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:  # Left mouse button.
                    # Spawn an entity.
                    radius = random.randrange(20, 50)
                    self.all_sprites.add(Entity(flipy(pg.mouse.get_pos()), self.space, radius))

        if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:  # Right mouse button.
            radius = random.randrange(20, 50)
            self.all_sprites.add(Entity(flipy(pg.mouse.get_pos()), self.space, radius))

    def run_logic(self):
        self.space.step(1/60)
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(pg.Color(140, 120, 110))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)  # Draw the images of all sprites.

        # Draw the static lines.
        for line in self.static_lines:
            body = line.body
            p1 = flipy(body.position + line.a.rotated(body.angle))
            p2 = flipy(body.position + line.b.rotated(body.angle))
            pg.draw.lines(self.screen, pg.Color('lightgray'), False, (p1, p2), 5)

        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game().run()
```

[image]

I also tried to find a way to hide these direction/rotation lines that `debug_draw` creates and found out that the lines are colored in the `draw_options.shape_outline_color` and the circles use the `draw_options.shape_dynamic_color` by default. So, when you set

```
draw_options.shape_outline_color = draw_options.shape_dynamic_color
```

the circles are completely blue. However, if you assign a specific `color` to each shape, it will still use the blue color for the lines.

And with the `draw_options.flags` attribute, I could only turn off the collision points or the shapes completely but not the lines:

```
# This is how you can turn off the collision points.
draw_options.flags ^= draw_options.DRAW_COLLISION_POINTS
# Stops drawing the constraints.
draw_options.flags ^= draw_options.DRAW_CONSTRAINTS
# Stops drawing all shapes.
draw_options.flags ^= draw_options.DRAW_SHAPES
```

Comment: If you don't know how classes, objects and pygame sprites work, I recommend reading chapter 12 and 13 of [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com).

Comment: Thanks! I'm already storing all balls' attributes (color, position, radius) in lists, for other purposes, so using pg.draw.circle() is pretty straightforward. Your example helped a lot.

Comment: Ah yes, I actually wanted to link the official [using_sprites.py](https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/examples/using_sprites.py) example in which a list is used as well (if you're not familiar with classes and pygame sprites).

Comment: Btw, if you don't want to use an auxiliary function like flipy, you can also set the variable pymunk.pygame_util.positive_y_is_up to False.